# Custom attributes not getting garbage collected?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-management, attributes, garbage-collection

In my WPF application we have various custom controls, dependency properties in these controls use various attributes like `SortOrder`, `MaxLength` etc.; these attribute values are used in `PropertyGrid` control to identify Sort Order etc. for a particular property.

Using ANTS profiler I came to know that these attribute objects always remain in memory, even though original custom controls are no longer in memory. Profiler shows this retention graph for these attributes - http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/akjoshi/CustomAttributeRetentionGraph.png

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Attribute` is associated with type and not an instance of a type.

Whenever a type is loaded, all attributes will be loaded associated with that type. And this will only happen once for a type, which means if you create 100 instances of that type, attributes will be loaded only once.

I guess they stay in memory till application exits.

Comment: What about attributes(having property scope) associated with a Property(DP)? I can see new instances being created with each new object.

Comment: `Properties` and `Fields` are part of `Type`. They are also loaded once per type.

Comment: Ok, so say I am associating an attribute with 300 properties, then 300 objects of this attribute will stay in memory(once object is created) even after control is destroyed.